# Does ignore_malformed ignore the field or the document?

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

I created an elasticsearch index with the setting `index.mapping.ignore_malformed` set to true. I had assumed this ignores malformed fields, but still indexes the rest of the document. For example, a document like this:

```
{ "disease" : "Cholera", "numCases" : "NaN" }
```

would be indexed as:

```
{ "disease" : "Cholera" }
```

However, when I ran a bulk import operation via MongoDBRiver, about 1/3 of the documents in the original database were not indexed, and there were no errors reported in `elasticsearch.log`. So, I'm wondering if the ignore_malformed setting could have caused this by ignoring any document that contains a malformed field.

Comment: Hm, it should index the document... what version of ES and what type `numCases` is (assuming `integer`?)?

Comment: ES version 1.2.2. numCases should be an integer, but it is dynamically inferred, so it could be some other numeric type.

Comment: Works for me. Tested with 1.2.2. I suggest performing a test without Mongo river.

Comment: Alexander Reelsen posted May 30 2013 on the ES mailing list that it ignores the field, not the document. Pinged him on Twitter in the hope he'll chime in.